# How to show recently record list on my custom visualforce page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

[The sObject's record list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAveM.png)

Hey, I have a question, when I click a sObject's tab it will present a standard page. The picture shows the recently record list, is it a standard function like "apex:listViews" mark-up tag? I want to achieve this function in my own custom page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a dedicated VF tag for it (aside from some very specialised cases like Knowledge and Ideas-related tags). But you can manually query it from database and display in `<apex:pageBlockTable>`.

There's a table with "recently viewed everything, across all objects" (think of it like "Recent Items" sidebar in clasic SF UI): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm

And also most objects will have a `LastViewedDate` field so you should be able to do

```
SELECT Name
FROM Restaurant__c
WHERE LastViewedDate != null
ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you , I will have  a try:)